# What is the minimum role for Google Analytics 4 Bigquery link

Tags: google-bigquery, google-analytics-4

I want to set GA4 Bigquery Linking on my client GA4 Property, and Export data to My GCP Project.

As
https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3416092?hl=en#zippy=%2Cin-this-article
mentioned, I gave Project "Editor" permission to my client account, and my client created GA4 link to My GCP Project, then It works correctly.
But I think "Editor" permission is too much, is there minimum permission for GA4 bigquery link?

Thanks,

[image]

Project role for client user is

- bigquery.bireservations.get
- bigquery.bireservations.update
- bigquery.capacityCommitments.create
- bigquery.capacityCommitments.delete
- bigquery.capacityCommitments.get
- bigquery.capacityCommitments.list
- bigquery.capacityCommitments.update
- bigquery.config.get
- bigquery.config.update
- bigquery.connections.create
- bigquery.connections.delegate
- bigquery.connections.delete
- bigquery.connections.get
- bigquery.connections.getIamPolicy
- bigquery.connections.list
- bigquery.connections.setIamPolicy
- bigquery.connections.update
- bigquery.connections.updateTag
- bigquery.connections.use
- bigquery.dataPolicies.create
- bigquery.dataPolicies.delete
- bigquery.dataPolicies.get
- bigquery.dataPolicies.getIamPolicy
- bigquery.dataPolicies.list
- bigquery.dataPolicies.setIamPolicy
- bigquery.dataPolicies.update
- bigquery.datasets.create
- bigquery.datasets.createTagBinding
- bigquery.datasets.delete
- bigquery.datasets.deleteTagBinding
- bigquery.datasets.get
- bigquery.datasets.getIamPolicy
- bigquery.datasets.listTagBindings
- bigquery.datasets.setIamPolicy
- bigquery.datasets.update
- bigquery.datasets.updateTag
- bigquery.jobs.create
- bigquery.jobs.delete
- bigquery.jobs.get
- bigquery.jobs.list
- bigquery.jobs.listAll
- bigquery.jobs.listExecutionMetadata
- bigquery.jobs.update
- bigquery.models.create
- bigquery.models.delete
- bigquery.models.export
- bigquery.models.getData
- bigquery.models.getMetadata
- bigquery.models.list
- bigquery.models.updateData
- bigquery.models.updateMetadata
- bigquery.models.updateTag
- bigquery.readsessions.create
- bigquery.readsessions.getData
- bigquery.readsessions.update
- bigquery.reservationAssignments.create
- bigquery.reservationAssignments.delete
- bigquery.reservationAssignments.list
- bigquery.reservationAssignments.search
- bigquery.reservations.create
- bigquery.reservations.delete
- bigquery.reservations.get
- bigquery.reservations.list
- bigquery.reservations.update
- bigquery.routines.create
- bigquery.routines.delete
- bigquery.routines.get
- bigquery.routines.list
- bigquery.routines.update
- bigquery.routines.updateTag
- bigquery.rowAccessPolicies.create
- bigquery.rowAccessPolicies.delete
- bigquery.rowAccessPolicies.getIamPolicy
- bigquery.rowAccessPolicies.list
- bigquery.rowAccessPolicies.setIamPolicy
- bigquery.rowAccessPolicies.update
- bigquery.savedqueries.create
- bigquery.savedqueries.delete
- bigquery.savedqueries.get
- bigquery.savedqueries.list
- bigquery.savedqueries.update
- bigquery.tables.create
- bigquery.tables.createIndex
- bigquery.tables.createSnapshot
- bigquery.tables.delete
- bigquery.tables.deleteIndex
- bigquery.tables.deleteSnapshot
- bigquery.tables.export
- bigquery.tables.get
- bigquery.tables.getData
- bigquery.tables.getIamPolicy
- bigquery.tables.list
- bigquery.tables.restoreSnapshot
- bigquery.tables.setCategory
- bigquery.tables.setIamPolicy
- bigquery.tables.update
- bigquery.tables.updateData
- bigquery.tables.updateTag
- bigquery.transfers.get
- bigquery.transfers.update
- bigquerymigration.translation.translate
- resourcemanager.projects.get
- resourcemanager.projects.setIamPolicy
- serviceusage.services.enable

Comment: Hi @Satoshi Watanabe, can you provide the images in English language?

Comment: Hi, Thank you for comment. I'm checking how to change language on GA Console

Comment: Hi @ShipraSarkar I added image in English, Please check.

Answer (score 2):

After several attempts I found this firebase documentation and the roles you need:

[Firebase Permission](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/iam/permissions)

So what I did was to add a custom role with

```
serviceusage.services.enable
resourcemanager.projects.get
resourcemanager.projects.getIamPolicy
resourcemanager.projects.setIamPolicy
```

And additional, add in the IAM console to the user that performs the binding the permissions of:

```
Service Usage Viewer (roles/serviceusage.serviceUsageViewer).
```

The other thing is that the custom role can have only the role of:

```
serviceusage.services.enable
resourcemanager.projects.setIamPolicy
```

and add the roles of:

```
Project IAM Admin (roles/resourcemanager.projectIamAdmin)
Service Usage Viewer (roles/serviceusage.serviceUsageViewer)
```

I hope you find it useful.

Answer (score 0):

You can provide below roles ( On Project or Dataset)

1. roles/bigquery.admin
2. (roles/bigquery.dataEditor)
3. BigQuery Data Owner  ( Only on target Dataset )
   (roles/bigquery.dataOwner)

Comment: Thank you Vishal,

It seems I need serviceusage.service.enable, resourcemanager.projects.setIamPolicy and bigquery.admin. but I got error when create link. There is no information about error type.

Any Ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure how to add image to comment, so I added images to my post.